# Copy post from category to custum post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I have 1458 post in category name news that id is 5.

And i wont to copy all of this post and transfer it to custom post type name news.

How can do that ??

Answer (score 1):

Create your custom post type and then try this. (BACKUP FIRST AS THIS IS UNTESTED).

```
<?php

// Get all posts in category "5"
$news_posts = get_posts(
    array(
        'category'  =>  5
    )
);

// Loop through them
foreach($news_posts as $p):

    // Update the post type
    wp_update_post(
        array(
            'ID'        =>  $p->ID,
            'post_type' =>  'news'
        );
    );

    // Delete term relationships for the post
    wp_delete_object_term_relationships( $p->ID, 'post_tag' );
    wp_delete_object_term_relationships( $p->ID, 'category' );  

endforeach;

?>
```

Comment: See my edits RE deleting term relationships..

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest an export/import procedure using a tool such as WP CSV.  https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-csv/

We use this plugin quite a bit for importing non-WP data and it's very reliable.

1. Register your CPT (via your plugin or theme functions)
2. Create at least one post in your CPT
3. Export with WP CSV to use as an import template
4. Export your 1458 category posts
5. Copy / paste these into the correct columns in your CSV file for import
6. Import the file as your new CPT posts
7. Confirm all is well and accurately imported
8. Delete the 1458 now duplicated posts from their original category home

I would test this entire operation on a copy of your live site.  Do this to a dev site - NOT a live production site.

Comment: are this steps support custom post type ?

Comment: Yes- CPT = Custom Post Type